# How to setup a self contained project running jetty+sinatra+jruby?

Tags: jetty, jruby, sinatra

I already installed jruby and gems seems to be installed nicely under jruby's directory so I don't have to worry about that. Now I would like to be able create a sinatra application and run it on top of jetty or some other efficient standalone server? What do you recommend?

It would be important for me that the application source can be modified, it's easy to start and everything needed except java is in a single directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jetty-rackup](http://github.com/geekq/jetty-rackup) was just what I was looking for. I don't need to do any jetty specific, just write config.ru and jetty-rackup handles everything.